# create_ap systemctl service failing

Tags: 18.04, server, dnsmasq, wireless-access-point

I setup config for [**create_ap**](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap)

```
$ cat  /etc/create_ap.conf
CHANNEL=default
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
WPA_VERSION=2
ETC_HOSTS=0
DHCP_DNS=gateway
NO_DNS=0
NO_DNSMASQ=0
HIDDEN=0
MAC_FILTER=0
MAC_FILTER_ACCEPT=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.accept
ISOLATE_CLIENTS=0
SHARE_METHOD=nat
IEEE80211N=0
IEEE80211AC=0
HT_CAPAB=[HT40+]
VHT_CAPAB=
DRIVER=nl80211
NO_VIRT=0
COUNTRY=
FREQ_BAND=2.4
NEW_MACADDR=
DAEMONIZE=0
NO_HAVEGED=0
WIFI_IFACE=p2p0
INTERNET_IFACE=eth0
SSID=MyHotspot
PASSPHRASE=852172777222
USE_PSK=0
```

but when I started systemctl service of create_ap it continuily failing with this error

```
Network Manager found, set p2p0 as unmanaged device... DONE
/usr/bin/create_ap: line 1704: dnsmasq: command not found
ERROR: Wrong version format!
Doing cleanup.. done
```

Answer (score 0):

As specified by the error you're missing `dnsmasq` in your system.
Just install it and it should works.

```
$ sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

Comment: this fixes problem that it does not error but it takes too much time to connect to the created wifi hotspot. and even after it gets connected I cannot ping other computers on the network

Comment: Can you `ping` the wifi client from the host ? Does the client have valid IP and Gateway ? Some errors in log file ?